# Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection auto resolve objects dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Previously I was using Unity for dependency injection, and it automatically resolved dependency's for me that code looked something like this:

```
IUnityContainer UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
UnityContainer.RegisterType<IDataProvider, DataProvider>();
```

Some class to have `IDataProvider` injected into:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private IDataProvider dataProvider;
    public SomeClass(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
         this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }
}
```

To resolve the dependencies for this object with unity I could simply type

```
SomeClass myClass = Unity.Resolve<SomeClass>();
```

And it would automatically try to inject the required constructor parameters from its ServiceCollection. Due to Unity being depreciated now, I've been trying to make the switch to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, I've got the IServiceProvider setup and can return requested services, however I'm yet to figure out how to use this library (and if I need extra librarys for this functionality) top achieve the same result.

Comment: I think in the case of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection you have to register(addtransient, addscoped etc) SomeClass too and then request an instance of that class using GetService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature that is *not* supported by MS.DI and it contains *no* hooks that would allow you add this feature on top of MS.DI. If you choose to stick with MS.DI, you will have to register `SomeClass` in the container, either explicitly or using Auto-Registration; there's no way around this.

Explicit registrations means that you have a line of code for each class that you want to register, e.g.:

```cs
services.AddTransient<SomeClass>();
```

With Auto-Registration on the other hand, you apply [Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) and use Reflection to find types at runtime. For instance:

```cs
var types =
    from type in typeof(SomeClass).Assembly.GetTypes()
    // Define your convention here
    where typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type)
    where ...
    select type;

foreach (Type type in types)
{
    services.AddTransient(type, type);
}
```

`Auto-Registration` scales much better than the `Explicit Register` approach. This does require, however, some sort of convention that can be distilled out of the classes you wish to register using Reflection.